# Select first child of class in different parents

Tags: html, css

I want the first div with class `.labelinput` in different parents to be selected. I do not want to select by parent because I have different parents. Is it possible to define only once?

Tried:

```css
div.labelinput:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="labelinput">style this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <div class="labelinput">style this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
</div>

<!-- ... -->

<div class="seventeen">
  <div class="labelinput">style this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you tried?  That should simply work.

Comment: It just does not style, I will post a better example

Comment: Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/L059m8cy/

Comment: That fiddle has a considerably more complex markup, and in particular, the "labelinput" is *never* the first child of a surrounding div, which is why it won't match your rule

Comment: Either rephrase the question, or ask a new one - as it stands, this question makes no sense: the code in the question works just fine.

Comment: I think OP originally had syntax errors in his Html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is working just be more specific:

```css
div div.labelinput:first-child {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="labelinput">style this</div> 
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <div class="labelinput">style this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
</div>
<div class="seventeen">
  <div class="labelinput">style this</div>
  <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
 <div class="labelinput">not this</div>
</div>
```

After OP comments the final solution is:

```
div div.labelinput:nth-of-type(2) {
   border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I see your example works, but I cannot get it to work in my code. My classes one, two etc are nested deep down, can this be a problem?

Comment: Nope as soon as div with class `labelInput` is child of a div. take a look here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/grq2zgo2/). Also you have a live example with whole code?

Comment: I do not have a live example, it is weird, none of your answers styles the first labelinput :(

Comment: This is not the same html with OP. You can you `:nth-of-type` like [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/L059m8cy/1/)

Comment: Okay I am sorry. Does this work if I have another number of divs before the first labelinput also? What does the hard coded 2 mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64119/discussion-between-alex-char-and-indianer).

Comment: Note that the `div > div` part of the selector is unnecessary in both your example and the OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

```
div .labelinput:first-child {
   border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

See http://jsbin.com/cupisefore/1/edit

Comment: OP example works. Wants to style the first div with class `.labelinput`. In this answer you select the first element inside div with class `.labelinput`

Answer (score 1):

First of type also works:

```
div.labelinput:first-of-type {
    border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/x7Lcutvx/9/